# Is everything Middleware if I use (var app = builder.Build()) app.xyz() in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, middleware

```
var app = builder.Build();
#region swagger
app.SwaggerAppBuild();
#endregion
app.UseHttpLogging();
app.UseMiddleware<RequestMiddleware>();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();

so on...
```

Here app.SwaggerAppBuild() is a custom extension method ..I used for Swagger ..Its only fired when the application starts.I want to know what is usage of "app".What kind of operation should call here? is every thing will act like middleware if I call them by "app"?My understanting is middleware called every http request.

The method code is :

```
public static void SwaggerAppBuild(this WebApplication app) { 
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) 
    { 
        app.UseSwagger(); 
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { 
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1"); 
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "API v2"); 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your ques ?

Comment: All of this is middleware no matter what order it's called. It's middleware because it adds methods that intercept and affect HTTP requests.

Comment: Your method adds the Swagger middleware so yes, order is important. The Swagger middleware needs to be installed in the proper place in the HTTP pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, yes, everything you add there is middleware and order-dependant.

I assume, that inside `SwaggerAppBuild`, there are the 2 calls to use the swagger middleware:

- `UseSwagger`
- `UseSwaggerUI`

In this case the `UseSwagger` middleware is indeed called on each request:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
{
    if (!RequestingSwaggerDocument(httpContext.Request, out string documentName))
    {
        await _next(httpContext);
        return;
    }

    try
    {
     /* ...*/
}
```

On each request the middleware checks, if the request path is actually matching a certain value, and if not, it just invokes the next middleware in place. If it matches a certain criteria, it will generate a JSON or yml document for you.

The same is true for `UseSwaggerUI`. Only this component is creating a static file and a bespoke static file middleware for you and renders the ui for you in it. (very simplified).

You can check the actual implementation over at:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

and the source codes for the middleware:

- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger/SwaggerMiddleware.cs
- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/SwaggerUIMiddleware.cs

Comment: public static void SwaggerAppBuild(this WebApplication app)
        {
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1");
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "API v2");
                });
            }

        }
this is the method ..when I debug it my pointer hits only one time when the application starts .. is it because ..this is not a middle ware ..or anything else ?

Comment: I've written it in my answer. It is middleware. The source code is there for you to read. The fact that you cannot debug this part is, because the package does not contain symbols AND you probably have enabled "Enable Just My Code (Managed only)" in Debug options. The gory details are abstracted away from you. If you'd go through the whole sdk line by line, you'd never see the end of the day.

Comment: @josephrozario add the code in the question itself. Your method isn't itself middleware but *installs and configures* middleware. Your `SwaggerAppBuild` is essentially just a way to group the code that adds the Swagger middleware through `UseSwagger` and `UseSwaggerUI`